# Calculating $\prod\limits_{k=0}^\infty(1+{\rm e}^{-(2k+1)\pi})$

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

Someone computed it by Mathematica and got that
$$\prod_{k=0}^\infty(1+{\rm e}^{-(2k+1)\pi})=2^{\frac14}{\rm e}^{-\frac\pi{24}}.$$
However, I don’t know how to prove it.

I would appreciate it if someone could show some suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Look for special values of theta functions.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ramanujang-andG-Functions.html, and http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram06.pdf

Comment: @River Li  Thanks a lot!